# Python find smallest multiple of numbers from 1-20. What is the issue in my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Yes, it's [Euler problem 5](http://projecteuler.net/problem=5). I'm new to python and I'm trying to solve a couple of problems to get used to the syntax. And yes I know that there are other question regarding the same problem, but I have to know why my code is not working:

```
import sys

def IsEvDivBy1to20(n):
    for i in range(1,21):
        if n%i!=0:
            return 0
    return 1

SmallMultiple = 0
for i in range(sys.maxsize**10):
    if IsEvDivBy1to20(i) == 1:
        SmallMultiple = i
        break

print(SmallMultiple)
```

It returns `0`.

Comment: wow.. Why do you have `sys.maxsize**10` ?

Comment: I understand that you are new to Python - it would help if you followed the [PEP-8 Python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) Which will help other users understand your code better. For a start - stop using CamelCase except for Classes, and start using lowercase_with_underscore. have white space on either side of mathematical operations, include spaces after commas, etc etc... "return 1" will work, but in Python best to "return True"

Comment: It returns 0 cause your `range(sys...)` starts from zero....

Comment: You shoudln't ask for solutions. Your code is not the best approach to this problem either. (Get rid of the sys.maxsize for example)

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: I have used sys.maxsize**10 as there is no sys.maxint in python 3.3 and I don't know how to do an "infinite" loop.

Comment: If you really intend on brute-forcing, there's a much smaller upper bound to this problem than `maxsize**10`: `math.factorial(20)`, which is roughly 10**172 times smaller on my box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`range()` by default starts at 0. The first time through your loop, then, `i` is 0: and so the first time through your (horribly-named) function, the values being compared against are 0.

Comment: So how to do an "infinite" range starting at 1?

Comment: @fishmong3r The same way you did in your other `for` loop.

Comment: @fishmong3r: `for i in itertools.count(1)`.

Comment: @tobias_k like `range(1,)`?

Comment: @fishmong3r `range(x)` is "from 0 to x-1", `range(x, y)` is "from x to y-1", so you could use `range(1, reallyLargeNumber)` or e.g. a `while` loop. And your function's name should be `is_even_div_by_1_to_20` by convention.

Comment: @tobias_k Thank you, I will use this naming convention as of now.

Answer (score 3):

Your code fails because,

```
range(sys.maxsize**10)
```

The first value returned by `range` is 0 and every number between 1 and 21 divides 0 without leaving any remainder. So, 0 is considered as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Also: Euler problems are not about brute forcing, it's also about finding an efficient solution.

For example, if a number is evenly divisible by the numbers 1 - 20 you can simply multiply 1 * 2 * ... * 20 = ... to find an upper bound. This number would clearly satisfy the conditions but it's likely not the smallest number.

You can then reason as follows: if the number can be divided by 6 then it can also be divided by 2 and 3. So I don't really need to include 6 in the 1 * 2 * ... * 20 multiplication. You can repeatedly apply this reasoning to find a much smaller upper bound and work your way towards the final answer.